# Laravel 4 Installation Error (via composer) always Timeout

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, installation, composer-php

I tried installing laravel.

I installed xampp then the composer.

I followed the documentation but when i'm installing laravel, i always get this:

http://i975.photobucket.com/albums/ae238/Mochi_Ongpin/help_zpsb8870025.png

Can someone please help me? I already tried several times but failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Laravel is already installed, it timed out in the very last thing it does, which is create the compiled classes files `bootstrap/compiled.php`. If this file is present, delete it (it's not really necessary) and try to use your Laravel installtion.

Why is it timing out? Not sure, but you can, later, try to execute the command manually:

```
php artisan optimize
```

**EDIT:**

You successfully installed a Laravel application, but there is at least one other variable in this process: **a web server**. Without it you cannot see that success message.

Being on Windows you probably will have to install Apache 2 or WAMP, then create a Virtual Host for your Laravel application and hit: `http://localhost/` to see that message.

You can also try to use Laravel's internal PHP server:

```
php artisan serve
```

And in your browser go to

```
http://localhost:8000
```

Comment: i got this: http://i975.photobucket.com/albums/ae238/Mochi_Ongpin/help2_zps2904e250.png am I done? thanks sir BTW :)

Comment: I want to ask why there is a success message on other installation vids that i watch. then in the screenshot i dont have it? thanks for helping sir :)

Comment: it was working thank you. Last question is it normal if i dont have the "Application key bla bla bla set successfully" on the command prompt during installation?

Comment: It's not a problem, you can check/change your key in the file `app/config/app.php`, look for `Encryption Key`.

Comment: 'key' => 'YourSecretKey!!!' so this is it? Thank you very much sir I appreciate your help Thank you very much I need to learn laravel so badly. Thank you again sir God Bless you.